# How to install android apk with authorization

Tags: android, apk, adb

I want to install my apk (my own application) to an android device, but this apk should be installed only if user is allowed to install (i.e. login needed)

I know that adb can be used to install an apk but I couldn't find any information about if I can protect adb port by a password. And, I don't know whether are there other methods or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the installation of an APK on a device. However, you can make the app working only on the devices you want, by adding a login form or a check on the unique ID of the device.

Keep in mind that a third person can bypass this protection by patching the app.